# Can we burninate the [javascriptlet] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [javascriptlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascriptlet) has 2 questions associated with it, with no usage guidance or tag wiki. The questions interpret the tag in two different ways. One question uses it to mean a java-scriptlet for which a tag [scriptlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scriptlet) already exists and the other means a javascript-let used in [tasker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tasker).

The four criteria for burnination:

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous? **No**
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site? **Not sure, it's confusing.**
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post? **Not as it stands now**
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts? **No**

Can we please burninate it?

Comment: Which of the two questions is about `let` in JavaScript like you say? I can't see where either question uses it.

Comment: I didn't mean the let keyword, I meant a small piece of JavaScript as in a scriptlet is a script-let.

Comment: I see. I agree, this seems incredibly unclear to me, even after googling. Annoyingly, there's the much more well-known `let` keyword in JavaScript, making searching for 'JavaScriptlet' nearly impossible. It seems there ought to be at least a Java-Scriptlet (in Java) which should be aliased to Scriptlet. Javascriptlets (in JavaScript), if those are a thing, should ostensibly exist, but *with* a wiki description, but it sounds to me like a JavaScriptlet is... just a JS file containing some runnable code?

Comment: I've voted to close one of the questions as unclear, since the OP there is asking for something using tags/an app that takes Java code, but accepted an answer written in JavaScript. The other appears to be a 'proper' use of the tag, but in that case (for [tag:tasker]), the term 'javascriptlet' just seems to be a term used by Tasker itself to refer to... JavaScript code snippets. That would render such a [tag:javascriptlets] tag 100% superfluous, in my opinion; you can just use the Tasker tag in conjunction with the JS tag.

Comment: Does it mean [tag:bookmarklet]?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 your suggestion would have made much more sense for the tag. But apparently not. One of the questions was about using some JS code in Tasker (an automation tool for Android) and this constitutes half of the usage of the tag. The other question is super unclear about what language it's even about but what it does mention is that the "javascriptlet" (whatever it is) has some input which is a variable (I think?) or maybe a string. Hard to tell. At any rate, not what I'd see in a bookmarklet.

Comment: [this doesn't require a burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/3956566), there's only two questions, the tag can simply be removed from both questions to remove it altogether.

Comment: There appears to have been at least one more question with the tag between 2015-09-18 and 2017-06. The earliest information we have is the tag was originally in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28878010/revisions), then removed by another editor, but re-added by that question's OP on 2015-03-18. The [other question we know about](//stackoverflow.com/q/44666780/) didn't exist until 2017-06-21. Tags used on only one question are supposed to be deleted after 6 months. So, either that didn't happen, or there was at least one more question with that tag during the above time period.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tags need to have a clear use case and we do burn many tags that are convoluted and end up with an array of questions utilising the tag with different meanings.

Given no one in the comments understood what the tag was supposed to mean and that there were only two questions in the tag, one actually closed as being unclear, I removed both tags from the two posts. The tag will die over night.

RIP [javascriptlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascriptlet)

There may be better ways to create such a tag, but in its current form it is not ideal. People should continue to use the [scriptlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scriptlet) tag with any other relevant tags.

Links to the two questions:

[How to search for a duplicate in a given string using scriptlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44666780/how-to-search-for-a-duplicate-in-a-given-string-using-scriptlet)

[Tasker Exported App Javascriptlet Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28878010/tasker-exported-app-javascriptlet-error)

Comment: Seems there is a third question asked a few days ago which also uses the tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56037057/populating-dropdown-using-js-function-getting-id-as-null

Comment: I removed it - the edit is pending review https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22996289